# capset fails with pointer to struct

Tags: c, struct, linux-capabilities

I have two code samples:
First, runs correctly:

```
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    __user_cap_header_struct *hdr = new __user_cap_header_struct;
    __user_cap_data_struct *data = new __user_cap_data_struct;
    hdr->pid = getpid();
    hdr->version = _LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION;
    data->effective &= ~CAP_TO_MASK(CAP_IPC_LOCK);
    data->permitted &= ~CAP_TO_MASK(CAP_IPC_LOCK);
    data->inheritable = 0;
    if (capset(hdr, data) < 0)
        printf("capset failed: %m");

    return 0
}
```

Second, `fail: Operation not permitted`:

```
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    struct __user_cap_header_struct hdr;
    hdr.pid = getpid();
    hdr.version = _LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION;
    struct __user_cap_data_struct data;   
    data.effective &= ~CAP_TO_MASK(CAP_IPC_LOCK);    
    data.permitted &= ~CAP_TO_MASK(CAP_IPC_LOCK);   
    if(capset(&hdr, &data))   
        printf("capset failed: %m");   

    return 0;
}
```

I think both code samples are the same.
When I run the first one it executes correctly (uses pointer to struct).
But the second fails (uses instance of struct).
I don't know why. Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely because how the structures are initialized. When declaring a local variable, its value is *indeterminate*, using that value then leads to *undefined behavior*.

The same goes for local structure variables. The member field values are simply undefined, so when you do e.g. `data.effective &= ~CAP_TO_MASK(CAP_IPC_LOCK);` you use an indeterminate (and seemingly random) value for the operation.

You need to initialize the structure to a well know value before using it. Like

```
struct __user_cap_header_struct hdr = { 0 };
```

The above will set all fields in the structure to zero.

When you allocate with `new` (which is C++ and not C!) then for structures (or classes) without default constructors all member fields are *default constructed*, and for integer fields this means they are zeroed. If you allocated the structures in the first example using `malloc` (as that's the C way of allocating memory) then you would have the same result as the second example, as then the allocated memory would not be initialized at all.

Comment: Right. Thanks Joachim!